# The probability of winning the lottery is $0.0186$. What is the $P(X<10)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

For $P(X<10)$, I summed up $(1-p)^{n-1} p$ from $1-9$.

$(0.0186)$

$(1-0.0186)^1 . (0.0186)$

$(0.9814)^2 . (0.0186)$

$ \vdots $

$(0.9814)^8 . (0.0186)$

and then added it up. Would that be correct? I ended up getting $0.4371$.

Also, I'm trying to figure out the probability i dont win a prize in the first 52 weeks. That would be $1 - (1-p)^{51} . p$, right? I wasn't too sure about this one.

Anything help would be appreciated

Comment: How is $X$ defined?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that X means week here. So P(X<10) is the probability to win in the first 9 weeks. Yes, you got it right.

Comment: For the 2nd one, why not, $(1-p)^{52}$? which is equal to $1-(p+p(1-p)+p(1-p)^{2}+....+p(1-p)^{51})$.